# Basic Javascript Inquiry Regarding Changing An Element's InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm working on a very, very, very basic website to practice with Javascript. This website's entire purpose is Rock, Paper, Scissors. I've already run into an issue. I cannot get the Javascript to edit a certain element's innerHTML. I've compared the code to other examples, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

This is the HTML:

```
<head>
<title> 
    Rock Paper Scissors 
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RockPaperScissors.css">
<script> type="text/javascript" src="RockPaperScissors.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>
    Rock | Paper | Scissors
</h1>
<br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button onclick="playerChoseRock();">Rock</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="playerChosePaper();">Paper</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="playerChoseScissors();">Scissors</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<div id="yourChoiceTitle">
    Your choice:
</div>

<div id="computerChoiceTitle">
    Computer's choice:
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="yourChoice">
    <p id="choiceWords">Your choice will be displayed here.</p>
</div>

<div id="computerChoice">

</div>

<div id="result">
    Results:
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
var gameOver = false;
var playerChoice = "";

var yourChoice = document.getElementById("yourChoice");
var computerChoice = document.getElementById("computerChoice");

function playerChoseRock() {
var playerChoice = "rock";
document.getElementById("choiceWords").innerHTML = "Rock";
}

function playerChosePaper() {
var playerChoice = "paper";
}

function playerChoseScissors() {
var playerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that when a player clicks on the "Rock" button, then it changes the text in #choiceWords to "rock" to make it known.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you put your script after your dom is ready?

Comment: +1 Nice job writing up your question. You included all of the info that someone looking to troubleshoot would need.

Answer (score 2):

Your script syntax isn't correct.

```
<!-----v---oops!----->
<script> type="text/javascript" src="RockPaperScissors.js"></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="RockPaperScissors.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured that out about 30 minutes after posting this. The forehead smack could be heard for miles around.